# Where to put logic dealing with more than one models

Tags: model-view-controller, business-logic

In an MVC framework like Rails, the overall consensus is to put business logic in the model. However, when it comes to logic like "get all problems that a user solved", I am not sure which model class I should put the logic, as the it needs to first look up all solutions submitted by the user, and collect the problem id from each solution, then the problem ids to get all the problems needed.

It feels more elegant to put it in the User model, so we can call something like `user.getAllProblemsSolved()`. However, all we need from the user instance is the user id. In places where no user instance is readily available, we have to create one just to call its `getAllProblemsSolved` method.

What is more, as the logic mainly deal with Problem and Solution models, it smells *Feature Envy* to put it in the User model. To avoid *Feature Envy*, it feels equally fine to put in Problem or Solution. Intuitively, I would put it in Problem to be like `Problem.getAllProblemsSolvedBy(userId)`, but I don't have good justification for that.

So where should I put that logic?

Comment: I tried to break your question up into a couple paragraphs; the massive wall of text was a little confronting.

Comment: Your problem stems from a misunderstanding. Yes, model should contain the business logic. **But "model" is not a class/object.** Instead, model is an application layer. What you refer to as "models" are actually instances of misused [activerecord](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) pattern. Please stop looking towards Rails as example of "properly implemented MVC", because it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that the relation between `Problem` and `User` is an m2m relation, so if you want to follow the rules and put the business logic in the model class, you can put `getAllProblemsSolvedBy` in the model class that is representing the m2m relationship, but using that logic the `getAllProblemsSolvedBy` will return problems ids, and then you'll have to get the problems from the `Problem` model class.

I would put it in the `Problem` model class as the method will return instances of `Problem` class.

---

**Update**
*Apr 23 2014, 07:00 UTC*

Note also that the m2m class, `Solution` in your case, depends on the existence of those two models `User` and `Problem`, so you can query both models from within this model, and therefore if I had an m2m model in my code I'd let it usually be responsible for querying both ends of the m2m relationship.

So for example in your case the `getAllProblemsSolvedBy` can be implemented in the `Solution` model class and it can return a list of `Problem` instances and can be passed an instance of `User`.

Comment: The m2m class is the Solution class. Separating the code to get problem ids from the code to get problems sounds like a good idea for better cohesion. The only concern is that now the controller needs to make two calls to the model instead of one.